# No known package when getting value for resource number

Tags: android, resources

Everything looks like ok.  But :

No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f040001

exception is throwing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My code was:

```
Resources res = getResources();
InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.xml.questions);
```

then I changed it to:

```
is = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.questions);
```

Now it works correctly :o

BTW, I had another problem  is:

```
WARN/System.err(577): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

This link solved: [Android parsing an xml with saxparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393696/android-parsing-an-xml-with-saxparser)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

> menu Project -> Clean

If it doesn't runs close project , close eclipse , and repeat...

and a tip , **don't touch gen code , it must be only change by eclipse itself**.

**MOD**

sometimes eclipse goes crazy with code . When it happens i usually change code order in res.
It happens to me with Strings , eclipse change the string to another one , and bug change when i change the order of some few strings there.

Comment: I have reset the emulator and load it again. I change the folder name from raw to xml and deployed again. But it is still same :(